# Logarithmic equation nonstandard.

Tags: logarithms

$$\log_{7 }(6 ^x+1) =\log_{3 }(4^x-1) $$
How can I prove that $x=1$ is the only solution without derivatives? If anyone can give me a hint or some point to start from I would appreciate. 
I found a solution.We know that $4^x-1>0 \Leftrightarrow x>0$
$$\frac{\log(6 ^x+1)}{\log7}=\frac{\log(4^x-1)}{\log3}$$
$$\Leftrightarrow\log3 \cdot \log(6^x+1)=\log7 \cdot \log(4^x-1)$$
We set $f(x)=\log3 \cdot \log(6^x+1)-\log7 \cdot \log(4^x-1)$and take $x_{1}>x_{2}$.
I evaluate $$f(x_{1})-f(x_{2})=\log3 \cdot \left [ \log(6^{x_{1}}+1)-\log(6^{x_{2}}+1)\right ]-\log7 \cdot \left [ \log(4^{x_{1}}-1)-\log(4^{x_{2}}-1)\right ]$$
$$f(x_{1})-f(x_{2})=\log3 \cdot \left [ \log{\frac{(6^{x_{1}}+1)}{(6^{x_{2}}+1)}}\right ]-\log7 \cdot \left [ \log{\frac{(4^{x_{1}}-1)}{(4^{x_{2}}-1)}}\right ]$$
$$f(x_{1})-f(x_{2})=\log3 \cdot \left [ \log{\frac{6^{x_{1}}(1+\frac{1}{6^{x_{1}}})}{6^{x_{2}}(1+\frac{1}{6^{x_{2}}})}}\right ]-\log7 \cdot \left [ \log{\frac{4^{x_{1}}(1-\frac{1}{4^{x_{1}}})}{4^{x_{2}}(1-\frac{1}{4^{x_{2}}})}}\right ]$$
$$f(x_{1})-f(x_{2})=$$$$\log3 \cdot \log6^{x_{1}-x_{2}}+\log3 \cdot \log{\frac{(1+\frac{1}{6^{x_{1}}})}{(1+\frac{1}{6^{x_{2}}})}}-\log7 \cdot \log4^{x_{1}-x_{2}}-\log7 \cdot \log{\frac{(1-\frac{1}{4^{x_{1}}})}{(1-\frac{1}{4^{x_{2}}})}}$$
$$(x_{1}-x_{2}) \cdot(\log3 \cdot \log6- \log7 \cdot \log4)+\log3 \cdot \log{\frac{(1+\frac{1}{6^{x_{1}}})}{(1+\frac{1}{6^{x_{2}}})}}+log7 \cdot \log{\frac{(1-\frac{1}{4^{x_{2}}})}{(1-\frac{1}{4^{x_{1}}})}}<0$$
So $f(x)$ is strictly decreasing and it is injective that means the equation has at most one solution that is $x=1$.

Comment: Utilise the change of base formula: $\log_b(x)=\log_d(x)/\log_d(b)$.

Comment: Without derivative it becomes really complicated to show.

Comment: $$\log_{7 }(6 ^x+1) =\frac{\log_{3 } (6 ^x+1)} {\log_{3} (7) }$$

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log_%7B7+%7D%286+%5Ex%2B1%29-log_%7B3+%7D%284+%5Ex-1%29+%3D